# Unable to create new feature for FeatureLayer with editor widget

Tags: editing, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, create, objectid

I´m using [this sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/ed_default_editingwidget.html) for default editor widget with the help of ArcGIS API for JavaScript. I replaced featurelayers with my own layer. It´s possible to update and delete features, but I don´t create/add new feature (console: *Error: Unable to complete operation.*). Can someone identify my problem ?
Can it be problem with creating of OBJECTID for new feature (I hoped that it could be created automatically) or somewhere in capabilities of service ?